# Обмен данными между формами

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться, почему когда я передаю указатель, он пустой.

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "a.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    A a;
    a.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

*a.h*

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>

class A : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    A(QDialog *parent = 0);
    void getData(QString, QString, QString);

private slots:
    void start();

private:
    QLineEdit *edit1;
    QLineEdit *edit2;
    QLineEdit *edit3;
};

#endif // A_H
```

*a.cpp*

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

A::A(QDialog *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *first = new QVBoxLayout;
    edit1 = new QLineEdit;
    edit2 = new QLineEdit;
    edit3 = new QLineEdit;
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Start");
    first->addWidget(edit1);
    first->addWidget(edit2);
    first->addWidget(edit3);
    first->addWidget(button);
    setLayout(first);
    setWindowTitle("Class A");
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start()));
}

void A::start()
{
    B *b = new B(this);
    hide();
    b->show();
}

void A::getData(QString str1, QString str2, QString str3)
{
    str1 = edit1->text();
    str2 = edit2->text();
    str3 = edit3->text();
    qDebug() << str1 << str2 << str3;
}
```

*b.h*

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "a.h"

class B : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    B(A *parent);

private:
    A *a;
};

#endif // B_H
```

*b.cpp*

```
#include "b.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>

B::B(A *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)//, a(*parent)
{
    //a = parent;
    QString str1, str2, str3;
    parent->getData(str1, str2, str3);
    qDebug() << str1 << str2 << str3;
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *second = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel *title = new QLabel("This is class B!");
    QLabel *label1 = new QLabel(str1);
    QLabel *label2 = new QLabel(str2);
    QLabel *label3 = new QLabel(str3);
    second->addWidget(title);
    second->addWidget(label1);
    second->addWidget(label2);
    second->addWidget(label3);
    window->setLayout(second);
    window->setWindowTitle("Class B");
}
```

Меня также смущает, что когда всплывает второе окно, оно пустое, хотя должен быть заголовок и текстовая метка "This is class B!".

Comment: Откуда, куда и какой указатель Вы передаёте? Простой копипаст кода не прибавляет вероятности получить вразумительный ответ без поясняющих комментариев со стороны автора вопроса.

Comment: В `main.cpp` создаю окно A. При клике на кнопку в окне А создается второе окно `B *b = new B(this);`. Указатель нужен, чтобы значение из QLineEdit'ов окна A передались в QLabel'ы окна B. 
При инициализации окна B пытаюсь обратиться к родителю: `parent->getData(str1, str2, str3);`, чтобы потом использовать эти значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас довольно много проблем в коде. Из того, что видно при непритязательном рассмотрении.

Прежде всего, это отсутствие указания родителей для виджетов в классе `B`. То, что Вы добавляете их в менеджер размещения, не говорит о том, что они будут иметь родителя, а это в свою очередь намекает на потенциальную утечку памяти.

Ваш класс `B` наследуется от `QMainWindow`, который в использовании немного отличается от диалога или даже просто виджета. У `QMainWindow` имеется специальный метод `setCentralWidget()`. Именно этим методом Вам необходимо воспользоваться, чтобы разместить Ваш `QWidget *window` в главном окне. Иначе будете видеть пустое окно `QMainWindow`.

Метод `A::getData(QString, QString, QString)` объявлен неправильно. Аргументами должны быть ссылки или указатели на переменные строк, иначе Вы не получите желаемые значения для них при выходе контекста выполнения из данного метода. Проще говоря, замените в объявлении и реализации код, например, следующим образом:

```
//! Объявление.
void getData(QString&, QString&, QString&);

//! Реализация.
void A::getData(QString &str1, QString &str2, QString &str3) {...}
```

При создании класса `B` Вы определяете ему в качестве родителя класс `A`, предварительно скрыв последний, но затем, показав дочернее. Это не вполне логично, т.к. состояние видимости также наследуется вместе с отношением родитель-потомок. Если уж желаете создать во всём независимые окна, то не делайте их зависимыми друг от друга отношением родитель-потомок. Это в общем-то не ошибка, Qt отработает правильно, но просто лёгкий дискомфорт появляется.

Что касаемо "пустого" указателя (как я понял, Вы намекаете на `this`), то я не вполне понял, каким образом Вы определили, что он пустой. Судя по тому, как он передаётся у Вас в коде, пустым он быть не должен по определению.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы абсолютно правы. Да, я забыл про `setCentralWidget()`.
Поменял аргументы функции на ссылки, и всё заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вам нужно указать парента для window.

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget (this);
```